# Why is my stdout interfering with my webpage in python?

Tags: python, cgi-bin, scapy

Really simple code that just fires one pcap (packet) using scapy,

If I just want to do simple cgi-bin POSTS to myself to run a set of 10 easy tests why is this just kicking back as text (rather than a website).  If I comment out the line

```
sendp(a, iface="em1")
```

Then the below code actually generates the website fine... but it won't actually send the packet, I imagine this is something with stdout.... suggestions are welcome!

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from scapy.all import *
#import v6tester_main

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>NPD Automation Tool - GCT-USG</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<font> NPD Automation Tool </font>'

a = Ether() / IP() / IPv6() / ICMPv6EchoRequest()
sendp(a, iface="em1")

print '<br>'
print '<font>End of Test</font>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

If I view source I see this->

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NPD Automation Tool - GCT-USG</title>
</head>
<body>
<font> NPD Automation Tool </font>

Sent 1 packets.
<br>
<font>End of Test</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see when you "view source"?

Comment: @JimGarrison hey added above, I am going to try to wrap a font tag around the sent 1 packets to see if that will work.... usually html is not so picky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the output of sendp brakes the HTML so bad it shows as text, 
what you can do is try pass verbose=0 to sendp (if the output is not important),
or try other verbose level.
if the output of sendp is important to you, you can run it in a separate script
with subprocess.Popen and try to format the output so it fit in the HTML page.

edit: ops, someone already answered with almost the same

Comment: Could you link me to what you are saying?  I am not sure I understand verbose=0...

Comment: I am up voting you buy not marking correct yet, trying to use the subprocess module right now and asked a different question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521055/why-cant-i-execute-another-python-script-using-the-subprocess-module-via-a-webs) going your route

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `sendp` doesn't just echo the package to stdout; it sends it "down the wire" at a lower protocol level. So if you want to send an html header you'll need to wrap it inside a package, not the other way around.

But are you sure you need to mess with scapy? If all you want is to send POST requests to a webserver, you can just use `urllib2.urlopen`. Put your POST data in the optional `data` argument, and it will use POST instead of GET for the request.

Comment: Haha sorry the two are completely separate, the website is just a wrapper so I can test a firewall with pcaps.  The web server is controlled through the em0 interface but the em1 interface is separate for FW testing, this is just a dummy pcap I am sending.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you are sending http data(eg Response Headers).

**You should be because it is being run off a web server**.

Comment: the pcap is just being sent out the wire, this is for firewall testing, this is just a dummy pcap so its just empty.  It is sent when its not commented out, but the website is then not generated...

Comment: I thought my first line is generating real HTML... it works for a lot of my other scripts... do you have a faq or how to page for what you are talking about :)

Comment: I didn't realise the script was running in a webserver(I looked at [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521055/why-cant-i-execute-another-python-script-using-the-subprocess-module-via-a-webs) ) so you should be sending the http data.